# Using System/getProperties in a Datomic query throws a FileNotFoundException

Tags: datomic

I am following the examples on the [docs](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html#calling-java) and am stuck at **Calling Java Methods**. When I run

```
[:find ?k ?v
 :where [(System/getProperties) [[?k ?v]]]]
```

I get a **FileNotFoundException Could not locate System__init.class or System.clj on classpath.  clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:463)**.

When I run `(System/getProperties)` in the REPL, I get results.

```
{"java.runtime.name" "OpenJDK Runtime Environment",
 "sun.boot.library.path" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64",
 "java.vm.version" "25.181-b13",
 ...}
```

I tried running the snippet with a fully qualified class name `(java.lang.System/getProperties)` and I still get the error.

```
(d/q '[:find ?k ?v
       :where
       [(java.lang.System/getProperties) [[?k ?v]]]
       [(.endsWith ^String ?k "version")]])
```

**Clojure Version:** `1.9.0`

**Datomic Version:** `[com.datomic/datomic-pro "0.9.5703"]` (on-prem)

Any ideas what I need to do to get this working? I am developing and running the REPL using IntelliJ.

Comment: Maybe try the fully-qualified class name, i.e `(java.lang.System/getProperties)`? Also, make sure to tell us what version / platform of Datomic you're running.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but still `FileNotFoundException Could not locate java/lang/System__init.class or java/lang/System.clj on classpath.  clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:463)`. Let me get the version details for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuart Halloway pointed out that he believes that it is a bug introduced with classpath function support. Datomic is incorrectly treating that symbol as a Clojure name.

The workaround is to give it a Clojure symbol to work with. For example:

```
(defn get-props [] (System/getProperties))

(d/q '[:find ?k ?v
       :where [(user/get-props) [[?k ?v]]]])
```